# Providing data for bunch of pages in next.js

Tags: next.js

I have the case, I think pretty common. I work with next.js and I want to get some data server side and I have plenty of pages that I want to use those data. So lets say I have pages of the form `/dashboard/[subpage]` and i have dozen `subpages` all of them need access to some common set of data from server ( also some specific as well but there is much common data). What I see I can do Is to provide `getServerSideProps` for each and every page and get needed data. Uh.. but this is nightmare, so many repetitions. I dig into docs and I see I can use on `_app.ts` level `getInitialProps` but this has huge disadvantages. From documentation :

```
Adding a custom getInitialProps in your App will disable Automatic Static Optimization in pages without Static Generation.
```

Its not acceptable. For me natural way would be to be able to create getServerSide props in the `/dashboard` root ( `dashboard/index.js`) and propagate those data deeper into tree but for some reason it's not like that in next.

I tried layouts as well but one more time from docs

```
Inside your layout, you can fetch data on the client-side using useEffect or a library like SWR. Because this file is not a Page, you cannot use getStaticProps or getServerSideProps currently.
```

Another fail :/

Can someone tell me what is common approach to this problem? Do I really have to repeat myself 15 (sic!) times ?!